# How to set the opacity of an element?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I have created some button elements using ng-repeat. Now I need to set opacity of those button elements based on the boolean value in JavaScript without ng-click because the opacity has to be set before any click events.

HTML

```
<div id="splash_btn_box_ng">
    <button id="{{button.buttonId}}" ng-click="setMode(button)" ng-repeat="button in buttons"></button>
</div>
```

I tried to set opacity in init() like the following,

```
$scope.buttons.buttonId.style.opacity = 0.3;
```

and ended up with the following error which means I think button was not created at the time I try to set opacity. So I could not achieve this in init():

> TypeError: Cannot set property 'opacity' of undefined

Comment: The error is saying `$scope.buttons.buttonId.style` is `undefined`.

Comment: ng-repeat creates six buttons in total. Out of those opacity should be set to  two buttons based on boolean value

Comment: Yes, because button is not created yet.

Comment: I can able to access the button in function"setMode(button)"  which was called in ng-click. But i could not access the same button inside init()

Comment: The `ng-init` directive can be abused to add unnecessary amounts of logic into your templates. There are only a few appropriate uses of `ngInit`. [1](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInit)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ng-class` directive to apply a css class conditionally like this :

The toggle opacity button is here for changing the state.

HTML :

```
<button id="{{button.buttonId}}" ng-class="{'low-opacity': isLow}" 
    ng-repeat="button in buttons">{{button.buttonId}}</button>
<hr>

<button ng-click="toggleOpacity()">Toggle opcaity</button>
```

CSS file :

```
.low-opacity {
  opacity: 0.3;
}
```

Controller :

```
  $scope.isLow = true;

  $scope.buttons = [
    {
        buttonId: 1
    },
    {
        buttonId: 2
    }
  ];

  $scope.toggleOpacity = function () {
    $scope.isLow = !$scope.isLow;
  }
```

Sample [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gladiatoriitoo/hzod8ufs/7/)

For more reference :

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass

Answer (score 1):

Don't do direct DOM manipulation like that, use `ng-style` or `ng-class` directives.
Template:

```
<button id="{{button.buttonId}}" ng-style="myStyle" ng-repeat="button in buttons"></button>
```

Controller:

```
$scope.myStyle = {'opacity': '.3'};
```

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngStyle

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass

Comment: Thanks. But opacity should be based on boolean value in controller. For example if $scope.currentValue = true means only the opacity of 0.3 should be set to the respective button

Comment: Still, ng-style and ng-class is the way to do that.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try ng-style ?

Example

HTML

```
<button id="{{button.buttonId}}" ng-click="setMode(button)"
        ng-repeat="button in buttons" ng-style="myObj">
  Welcome
</button>
```

Controller

```
$scope.myObj = {
        "opacity" : "0.3"
    }
```

[Angularjs ngStyle](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngStyle)

Answer (score 1):

Use `ng-style`:

```
<button id="{{button.buttonId}}" ng-style="button" ng-repeat="button in buttons"></button>
```

Controller:

```
$scope.button = {
    "opacity": "0.3"
}
```